# Nuxt 3 как отображать LaTeX?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Нужно отображать в компоненте данные где встречаются данные в LaTeX.

```
Combine like terms: $3k = 12 - 10.5$
Calculate the sum or difference: $3k = 1.5$
Divide both sides of the equation by the coefficient of variable: $k = \dfrac{1.5}{3}$
Multiply both the numerator and denominator with the same integer: $k = \dfrac{15}{30}$
Cross out the common factor: $k = \dfrac{1}{2}$
get the result: True
Answer: True
```

Нашел библиотеку для vue 2, но в nuxt 3 не получается ее подключить, или я не правильно это делаю.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/latex2vue

Может кто то подскажет либу которой можно было бы скормить подобный текст и что бы она отрендерила LaTeX?